# SP13: Remove Page Horizontal Scroll Bar

Tags: 2013, development, javascript, master-page

I have made changes to the master page on a SP13 page.  An horizontal scroll bar appears at the bottom of the page.  The following piece of code I have that adjusts the height of the scroll bar, but I am confused on how to remove the scroll bar.

```
<div id="s4-workspace" = style="height: 1250px; margin: 0 auto; width: 1150px">
```

style="height": 1250px changes the height.  I tried changing the "height" to zero, but did not work.

Does anyone know how to remove the horizontal scroll-bar?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest adjusting the width rather than the height to remove the horizontal scroll bar in your inline style. Try reducing the value of width and see if the scroll-bar disappears. Alternatively, don't specify a width at all.

However, if you do require a fixed width layout then the following article might prove useful.

http://www.n8d.at/blog/fixed-width-design-in-sharepoint-2013-the-fast-way/